# Reference to the pushed button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I wanted to make an easy python project with the use of tkinter. In the screen, I need 81 buttons, so I thought the easiest way to perform this is by double "for" cycle but, when one of the buttons is pressed I need to configure its text but I don't know how to refer to it. Thank you for the answers. Here is my take on the project:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x400")
root.title = "go"
lista=[]
def buttonfunction():
    configure(text="t")

for i in range(9):
    for e in range(9):

        Button(root, text="a", command = buttonfunction).grid(row = e, column = i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign function with argument using `lambda` but to use button you have to do it after creating this button.

You have to also use `x=btn` (if you run it in loop) to copy value from `btn` to new variable `x`. Without this all `command` will have access to the same (last) button.

```
def buttonfunction(widget):
    widget["text"] = "t"

btn = Button(root, text="a")
btn["command"] = lambda x=btn:buttonfunction(x)
btn.grid(...)
```

Comment: Thank you, it was really helpful.